# Cannot access network server

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, remote-desktop, windows-update

I have windows 10 on my PC and I connect through Ethernet to a windows 10 server. I had no issue with that since the last update of windows that I can no longer access the server through path `\\server`.

- I can connect with RDC to the server
- I can see the server on networks
- I can ping the server
- I **cannot** access through `\\servername`
- I **cannot** access through IP

My user profile has all the privileges of administrator but when I enabled the administrator account logged out of my account and logged in with administrator account everything worked! 
My user and administrator are members of all groups and have the same privileges, yet I cannot log in with my profile. Any idea what caused this after the update?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to delete your user from Administrator group and re-add it to check the results.

Also, create a new user account and add it into Administrators group, if it can work fine, we can consider that your original user profile was corrupted.

Let's delete the profiles after backing up the personal files and favorites, delete it under Advanced system settings, then, sign in with your original user account, and your profile will be recreated.

[image]